# How can I perform an arithmetic calculation in an HTML Email Template when the first operand is not a field reference?

Tags: email-template

I'm attempting to create an email that lets contacts know they have a certain number of tasks to complete until their next reward.

I know I can do `{!Contact.Chats__c - 10}` to get a value, but I need to subtract `Contact.Chats__c` from `10`.

Simply reversing the operands does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: You've tried {!10 - Contact.Chats__c}?

Comment: @BrianMansfield please submit as answer so I can mark it. Guess I don't fully understand SFDC syntax!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
{!10 - Contact.Chats__c}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

How about: `{!Contact.Chats__c * -1 + 10}` ?

By order of operations this is equivalent to subtracting it from 10.